# Which regular expression standard is used in grep?

Tags: linux, regex, grep, standards

Is the regular expression standard used in grep *POSIX + ASCII* or something else is mixed in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That all depends on which flags you pass to grep.

The normal flagless grep (which is the same as passing -G) uses "Basic regular expressions":

```
-G, --basic-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE, see 
    below).  This is the default.
```

If you specify -E it uses "Extended" regular expressions:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, 
    see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
```

And then you have -P for Perl regular expressions (PCRE):

```
-P, --perl-regexp
    Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.  This is highly 
    experimental and grep -P may warn  of  unimplemented features.
```

**Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions**

In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`,  `(`,  and `)` lose  their  special  meaning;  instead  use  the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`.

Traditional  egrep  did  not  support  the `{` meta-character, and some egrep implementations support `\{` instead, so portable scripts should avoid `{` in grep -E patterns and should use `[{]` to match a literal `{`.

GNU grep -E attempts to support traditional usage by assuming that `{` is not special if it would be the start of an  invalid interval  specification.   For  example,  the  command  `grep -E '{1'`  searches  for  the two-character string `{1` instead of reporting a syntax error in the regular expression.  POSIX.2 allows this behavior as an  extension,  but  portable  scripts should avoid it.

So although grep strives to be as close to POSIX as possible there are still some flaws in it.

Comment: Yeah, I rad that but it doesn't say which standard is actually used, and if it's a mix of stuff then there's no referance to the mixed standart. So basically we know that it works with something but don't know with what exactly. :D

Comment: @den: POSIX regular expressions are explained in [regex(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex), Perl's - [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: This is about Linux, but the "-P" option is not available under MinGW ("grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary"), at least not by default.

Comment: Different `grep`s understand (slightly) different REs (and flags, and...)

Comment: @PeterMortensen, [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) does support `grep -P`, I'm not sure if that helps. Cygwins grep does so as well, afaik